# Elasticsearch Upgrade issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing issue while upgrading elasticsearch from elasticsearch-6.8.11-1.noarch to elasticsearch-7.10.2-aarch64.rpm.

```
Current ES Version : elasticsearch-6.8.11-1.noarch
Current OS Version : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
Intend to Upgrade  : elasticsearch-7.10.2
Error              : Failed dependencies [ Highlighted below ]


**[root@dgraystg1 rpm]# rpm -Uvh elasticsearch-7.10.2-aarch64.rpm

warning: elasticsearch-7.10.2-aarch64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID d88e42b4: NOKEY

Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]

        package elasticsearch-0:7.10.2-1.aarch64 is intended for a different architecture**

[root@dgraystg1 rpm]# rpm -qa | grep elas

elasticsearch-6.8.11-1.noarch

[root@dgraystg1 rpm]# cat /etc/system-release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
```

I have tried upgrading the ES with the correct noarch package but its not working.

Comment: What is the cpu of your host ? Aarch64 is for arm based cpu.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DmiU.jpg)

I was making a mistake by directly upgrading from ES 6.8 to ES 7.10, whereas I followed the upgrade path as 6.8 -- 7.0 -- 7.10 and able to upgrade successfully.

Cheers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).